# CQRS tracking user changes

Tags: .net, design-patterns, cqrs

We are currently investigating new ways to build our (web)applications and one method comming to mind is CQRS. We still have several questions about this:

If I understand correctly this probably means having 2 or more domain models, one core domain model and one read model for the webapp.

This core domain model is not directly written to by the webapp but by a different service.
We are thinking about using NServiceBus to make a publisher / handler so the webapp can publish changes made by users. The subscriber will then handle the message and update the core domain model and the read model.

**What we want to achieve:**

User A creates 10 new objects, books for example.

the message subscriber has a lot of messages to process so it takes a couple of minutes before the domain models are updated.

When user A refreshes the page he should see the 10 books he has just created.

When user B refreshes the page he doesn't really have to see these items.

*Where do you best store these 10 new objects?*

*What is the best way to merge this data with the "old" data from the read model?*

Let's say user B does need to see these new items too, *what's the best way of storing this data then?*

*What is the best way to deal with adding the same book by 2 different users at the same time?*
(where all the data is the same, except the book description. It's still the same book:)

*What way can you handle updates to one of these 10 objects that are not yet written to the core domain model and therefore don't have an unique id?*

Comment: Complicated questions.  Are you sure you have a domain that is complex enough? All of your questions are valid for CQRS and have been answered (lookup eventual consistency for a start).

Answer (score 2):

**In my opinion** CQRS has many different aspects to think about. The core point I took away from it was the segregation of user's actions (commands -> write model) and displaying information (queries <- read model). I can then pick and choose the rest of the architectural patterns that naturally fit with this separation as appropriate depending on the applications requirements. Remember CQRS is not meant as a top level architecture and you should pick and choose from it and only use when appropriate.

From your questions I get the impression you haven't gotten very far with your research so I recommend the following; [Initial CQRS documentation](http://cqrs.wordpress.com/documents/), [Rinat Abdullin's Blog](http://abdullin.com/journal/2010/11/3/cqrs-architecture-and-definitions.html), [Jonathan Olivers Blog (read the older stuff)](http://blog.jonathanoliver.com/archives/), and [Rinat's CQRS guide (although I've yet to read through this site)](http://cqrsguide.com/).

I guarantee having read through the [CQRS documentation](http://cqrs.wordpress.com/documents/) you'll be able to answer your questions for yourself.

Perhaps if you tells us the patterns/technologies your looking to use, I can provide a more complete answer. But to get your started for your first question its is pretty straight forward:

> Where do you best store these 10 new objects?

The answer is that logically you store *parts* of your data in both write and read models; physically this could be stored in the same data store or different ones depending on the technologies and implementation you choose (eg sql-server database vs key-value no-sql solutions).

eg If you choose to use *event sourcing* then you store the events as they occurred in the write model. Your read model would store the data denormalized, crafted such that your screens can be composed from this data of your read model. But that's keeping true to the pattern as I see it; your read model could just store the data normalised with your query service executes actual sql queries against a realational database.

**EDIT following comment**

The system I'm currently working on doesn't use messaging although it does use events. Everything is **in-process**. So the the Command is handled; Event(s) are raised and handled all within the same unit-of-work. Basically the command handler wont finish until the appropriate event handlers have all completed.

We're still considering **out-of-process** event handlers when there's more intensive/complex updates to the read model. But at this stage there isn't a need for it, and it keeps things simple.

The whole eventual consistency aspect is just something that comes with the pattern. It will never be a problem for 'other' users but for the user who has just submitted and then refreshed the page I can see this being confusing to not see an update they've just submitted. Personally I don't like the idea of faking an update because it's like doubling up on the effort. Instead I prefer the option of redirecting to an acknowledgement page giving more time for your application to process the messages.

Something that I'd personally like to explore further would be to track submitted commands and there associated out-of-process events handlers. Users refreshing a page that have messages yet to complete, could be notified of the incomplete messages. A notification could be 'pushed' to the client once the messages have finished processing. I'd make these notifications subtle so as not to distract the user or become annoying and in the way.

Comment: thanks for the extensive post. We've come to the conclusion that updating the read model should be done asap so clients will see the new information. The real question is: 
In what way is the changed data stored between the change by the user and the update of the read model? The update by the client creates a message through the servicebus. This could take several seconds or even minutes to be handled and therefore the read model to be updated. In the mean time, the user won't see his updates.

We know that we can fake this, but we don't know what would be the best way to do this.

Comment: We could store this in javascript, but what if the user refreshes the page. How do you handle large amounts of data in this scenario? We don't want the webapplication to write to our read model.